Receiving insufficient plan error in QField when downloading project from QFieldCloud
I have created a QGIS project for testing the remote collection of data using QField. I would like to synchronise data remotely, so I'm using QFieldCloud's Community plan.
I have uploaded my project to QFieldCloud successfully from QGIS using the QFieldSync plugin, but when I try to download the project into QField on an Android tablet, I receive the following error:
Downloading error. [HTTP/403] https://app.qfield.cloud/api/v1/jobs/ Server Error. {"code":"permission_denied_plan_insufficient","message":"Permission denied because the user account's plan is insufficient"}
My understanding is the Community plan allows for 100MB of data hosting, of which my project uses 647.5KB.
Not sure what info would help solve this, but here's the project/system specifics:
The project contains one GeoPackage layer for collecting data, and five layers grouped to form the basemaps (1 vector, 4 raster). The basemap layers are configured as a theme which is then set as a base map in the QField project properties. I do not want the basemap layers synchronising as that would push me considerably beyond the 100MB limit, so I have set the QField Cloud individual layers setting action to 'Directly access data source'. The basemap layers are localised in the QGIS project and manually placed on the device.
QGIS 3.36.1-Maidenhead (on Windows 11 10.0.22631 Build 22631)
QFieldSync 4.9.1
QField 3.3.2 Darien (on Android 11)
The project on QFieldCloud looks like this:

There are warnings in QFieldCloud that my basemap layers are localised so I need to ensure they are on the QField device, which they are (not that I can get as far as checking they display properly).
I have tried deleting the existing project in QFieldCloud, saving the project in QGIS with a different name, and uploading that as a different project, but the issue persists.
These questions:
QField: Permission denied plan insufficient and Synchronisation issue descibe the same error message, but I am neither exceeding the 100MB limit or using any PostGIS layers.

So it seems even though the basemaps are not uploaded, the file size is still the problem.
I have had success using a small mbtiles file with exactly the same config (localised, manually copied onto tablet, definitely not stored in QFieldCloud).
I was hoping to use the larger, more detailed basemaps, but I can at least test the process with this. Even though I'm nowhere near the storage limit, to be able to use the larger basemaps I will need to upgrade my QFieldCloud account plan.

from what I can see from the screenshot the basemap is indeed not uploaded to the cloud, but I don't think "directly access data source" works by remotely accessing the file from your PC. I just think it means the basemap won't be copied in the local qfield project on your tablet, but will instead access and read the file directly from the cloud. since you don't have the basemap uploaded there is nothing for the tablet to read the map off of.
I added a screenshot of my own project as example
I have an mbtiles file that I use as a basemap, which appears in my cloud. the basemap only has the option to be read directly from the source (in my case the cloud) or be removed from the project. after fieldwork when I sync my qfield with qgis the only files that will be replaced on the cloud are the gpkg. for the gpkg I can have the option to directly access the data source, which would again be the cloud version.


if the basemap is so large that it can't be uploaded you can package your project for qfield, but you will have to manually add the project folder in your qfield directory, and manually take the modified project from qfield, to upload back to qgis. package for qfied and synchronise from qfield are both in the qfieldsync toolbar.

Thank you for your response. I admit I was unclear on the phrase 'directly access data source'. However, I did not expect this to mean it would directly access the data on my PC, rather as long as you configure a localised path and manually place the data using the same folder structure on the tablet, your project would be able to use it.

In fact, I have done this many times before in QField, but with placing the project data manually on the device via USB, allowing several projects to the same basemaps. Are you saying the absence of the basemaps in QFieldCloud causes the 'insufficient plan' error?

since you can't upload the basemap because of its size (hence the "insufficient plan" error) you can try to upload a simple mbtiles, and see whether you get the same error. I do think you're getting it because the basemap isn't uploaded. what's more, even if you somehow manage to upload the basemap to the cloud, you'd have to do the same for every project

if your basemap is present in your local qfield cloud directory, then every sync attempt will try to upload the basemap, but since it's too big it will give you the error

Hmmm, this is the strange thing, the basemaps are not present in the local QFIeld directory. As you suggest though I will make an attempt using a small mbtlies files, or even with no basemap configured at all.

So it seems even though the basemaps are not uploaded, the file size is still the problem. I have had success with a small mbtiles file with exactly the same config (localised, manually copied onto tablet, definitely not stored in QFieldCloud). Not ideal but I can at least test the process with this. To be able to use my previous basemaps I will need to upgrade my plan, even though I'm nowhere near the storage limit. Thanks @IonIon for your comments.
